# Extracting data from a log file with multi-line records to CSV

Tags: linux, database, parsing, csv

I have a search algorithm that parses through a log file and drops the findings into this format:

```
[Mon May  2 13:46:00 2016]Local/ESSBASE///139969058175296/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 0 minutes
--
[Mon May  2 13:46:00 2016]Local/ESSBASE///139969068702016/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 4 minutes
--
[Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016]Local/ESSBASE///139969078176064/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 6 minutes
--
[Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016]Local/ESSBASE///69062385984/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 45 minutes
--
[Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016]Local/ESSBASE///69160071488/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 3 minutes
--
[Mon May  2 13:46:02 2016]Local/ESSBASE///969053964608/Info(4052237)
Logging out user [accelatisro@Native Directory], active for 3 minutes
```

I need to get the date (IE: 5-2-2016 13:46:02), the user who was logged out (IE: accelatisro@Native Directory), and how many minutes they were active for (IE: 45). Then I need to write the results into a comma delimited format so I can upload the information to a database (IE: 5-2-2016 13:46:02,accelatisro@Native Directory,45).  The file is about 45,000 lines long so doing it by hand is a no can do.

What approach should I take for this problem?

Comment: "Please write this program for me" questions are not welcome here. Specifically, they're too broad -- not narrowed to a specific technical question.

Comment: Hmm. There probably *is* an allowable question hidden in this somewhere. Going to see if I can edit a little to pull it out.

Comment: yeah okay so what if your version of the question IS better :P

Comment: Heh. Do see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason/274665 for some discussion around community norms on the topic, btw. We really *do* frown on questions that don't show that you've made an effort to figure out a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach is to write a regular expression for each line you might need to match, then iterate through the file, filling in data from each matched line, and emitting that data whenever you see your record delimiter. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

l1_re='^\[([^\]+)]'
l2_re='Logging out user \[([^\]+)], active for ([[:digit:]]+) minutes'
delim='--'

flush() {
  [[ $time && $user && $minutes ]] || return
  printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "${time//,/}" "${user//,/}" "${minutes//,/}"
  time=; user=; minutes=
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $l1_re ]]; then
    time=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  elif [[ $line =~ $l2_re ]]; then
    user=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    minutes=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  elif [[ $line = $delim ]]; then
    flush
  fi
done
flush
```

With your given input, this emits:

```
Mon May  2 13:46:00 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,0
Mon May  2 13:46:00 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,4
Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,6
Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,45
Mon May  2 13:46:01 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,3
Mon May  2 13:46:02 2016,accelatisro@Native Directory,3
```

Comment: A couple questions:  How does this program take input? What does `-r` in the `while IFS= read -r line; do` do?

Comment: @Michael, the `read` reads a line from stdin, so the idea is that you'd run `./convert <in.log >out.csv`. See BashFAQ #1 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for background.

Comment: @Michael, ...the `-r` makes bashslashes be interpreted literally -- without it they're partially processed as escape characters, so `\\foo` would become `\foo` (as an example).